# Updating inherited property

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = {x: 1}
var bar = {__proto__: foo} // __proto__ specific to implementation
var bar = Object.create(foo) // same result as above with standard API 
console.log(bar.x) // 1
foo.x = 2
console.log(bar.x) // 2
bar.x = 3
console.log(foo.x) // 2
```

Why did updating the `inherited` property `x` by the child object `bar` take no effect on the parent object `foo` but the opposite do?

#### @EDIT

After its creation the child `own` property remains unaffected when the parent object updates the `shadowed` property now.

```
foo.x = 4
console.log(bar.x) // 3
```

Comment: If it would work the other way around, then it wouldn't be inheritance...

Comment: This question has been asked before here: [*The assignment operator does not change properties in prototypes*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820960/the-assignment-operator-does-not-change-properties-in-prototypes), but does not have a suitable answer yet.

Comment: Assigning works different than asking for the value or mutating it. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning to an object property creates or updates the object's own property, there is no search on the *prototype* chain for an inherited property.

See ECMAScript [Simple Assignment ( = ) §11.13.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1).

Answer (score 3):

It's all about prototypes. `bar` object has no `x` property, so when you try to access it, prototypes chain will be involved, and you will get value of `foo.x`. Then you update `foo.x`, and while accessing `bar.x` you will see another value also.

But when you set `bar.x`, `x` property will be created in `bar` object. `foo.x` is another one so it will stay the same.

*And you should avoid using `__proto__` in your code. It's browser specific feature (that's why it has underscores in name).*